# Beginner - I want to make ggplot on Shiny in R and I don't know where I made up mistake

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using Shiny in R to make two different tabs.
I think one tab would be a good idea to make a summary tab and another one is for the plot.
I want to give user a selection of x, y and color section... When I finished the part of ggplot section, the plot is not shown as I expected.
Please help me out where I made up mistake and please help me to understand of it.

Thank you.

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
new_mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  select(wt,mpg,cyl,vs,am,gear,carb)

# Define UI for an application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("prac"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     selectInput("xvalue","Please Choose X Value : ", c("wt","mpg")),
     selectInput("yvalue","Please Choose Y Value : ", c("wt","mpg")),
     selectInput("color","Please Choose color Value : ", choices =  c("cyl","vs","am","gear","carb"))
   ),
   mainPanel(
     tabsetPanel(#tabPanel("Information",tableOutput("info")),
                 tabPanel("Summary",tableOutput("summary")),
                 tabPanel("Comparison",plotOutput("plot")))
   )
  )
 
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  
))
```

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  df_sub <- reactive({
    new_mtcars[,c(input$xvalue,input$yvalue,input$color)]
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    category <- input$color
    ggplot(df_sub(), aes(input$xvalue,input$yvalue)) + 
      geom_point(aes_(color = as.name(category)),size = 3) +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm")
  })
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `input$xvalue` and `input$yvalue` are characters. To tell ggplot that it should look for variables with these names in your dataset

1. use `.data[[input$xvalue]]` and `.data[[input$yvalue]]` inside `aes()` or
2. use `aes_string` instead of `aes()`.

[image]

Comment: It totally work! thank you so much for giving me a great advice!! thank you so much!